# Set fix size of browser window on mobile screen

Tags: html, css, window, size, css-position

I am developing responsive site and have maybe a common problem, but i couldn't find the answer and need your advice. I want browser window fix on height:500px on mobile screen. Now i have this situation (look at the pic). I need to avoid white color below and want my container fit the whole screen and height not more then 500px.
Thank you for any advice!
[image: pic]

Comment: A possible solution would be to look at all the devices that you are targeting and find the one that has the smallest height.  For example if you are target all mobile devices and your know 300px to be the min height on all of your devices, set the min-height to 300px and the content should push everything else down.

Comment: Thank you for advice! But i need container not more then 500px height on mobile screen, want container to be short. But when i try to set , for instance - body {500px;} nothing happen

Comment: If your container is set to 500px height and the screen is let say 650px height you won't get the container to fill the whole screen that is the reason for the white space. If you want `responsive` rather use `%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Your container height and width to 100%.

```
#container
{
  height : 100%;
  width : 100%;
}
```

if you dont want your height to be more than 500px, you can use max-height property.

```
max-height : 500px;
```

Comment: if you want the whole screen to be occupied, then use height:100%;

Comment: that is the whole problem he wants max height 500px but to fill the whole screen which is not possible if the screen height is more than 500px. So your answer is not going to remove any white space on a screen with more than 500px height and it is not keeping max height to 500px with `height:100%;`

Comment: i dont think you can satisfy both the conditions at once. If you just want to remove the white space,try giving backgound-color to your body element.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers! Special thank for Jithin. I set width and height to 100% and use position:fixed for footer. Its working perfect. Thank you very much!)